# Ruby: multiple files, one "require" clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, include, partial-classes

I have several classes wrapped into one module to make namespace for them, stored in one file `my_namespace.rb`.

```
module MyNamespace
    class Class1
    end

    class Class2
    end

    class Class3
    end

    class Class4
    end

    class Class5
    end
end
```

This module is pluged in by one clause:

```
require 'my_namespace'
```

This module is bloated by now, so I want to split the namespace across several `*.rb` files in `lib` folder - one file per class, but am afraid that it will require to use several `require` clauses - one per class. How to keep one `require` clause? (Or more exactly: require, include or whatever allows me to use my classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate your require calls at load time by looking into the folder first.  eg

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "path/to/directory/*.rb")].each {|file| require file }
```

So, if all of your files were in the "/path/to/directory" folder they'd all get required.

Some people favour dropping the ".rb" part from the end of the require, in which case you would do

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "path/to/directory/*.rb")].each {|file| require file.gsub(/\.rb$/,"") }
```

EDIT - updated the paths to be inside the rails project folder, since they probably will be in there somewhere. In the above example, i've assumed that they are in `<your project folder>/path/to/directory`

There is a potential risk in this approach when using inheritance because files are listed probably in different order than inheritance requires. Even if you manage to name files so that inheritance works in Windows, Linux may sort files in a different order and this will ruin all your efforts. In such case an array of file names is recommended.

Comment: Where should I do this? Is it enough to do this in some base file so that main app code will require only this base file?

Comment: yep, put it in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Nice advice, but I thought about some "root module" of a package that could be included solely and holds all the requirements inside. I think about a package not as an application, but as a bunch of files in lib subfolder.

Comment: `Rails.root` is `nil` in beginning of `config/application.rb`. To take advantage of it the require loop should be defined after `class Application < Rails::Application`